# .effect('slide'... not showing next object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I was browsing around stackoverflow for slider and found this one http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tHZLY/2/ (Somehow I can't find the topic...)
code :

```
var $pages = $('.page');
$('#nxt').click(
  function() {
    var $cur = $('.active');
    var $next = $cur.next();

    if ($next.length == 0) return;

    $cur.removeClass('active');
    $next.addClass('active');

      $('.page').not('.active').effect('slide',{direction:'right',mode:'hide'});
      $('.active').effect('slide',{direction:'right',mode:'show'});
});

$('#prev').click(
  function() {
    var $cur = $('.active');
    var $prev = $cur.prev('.page');

    if ($prev.length == 0) return;

    $cur.removeClass('active');
    $prev.addClass('active');

    $('.page').not('.active').animate({"width": 0}, "slow");
    $('.active').animate({"width": 200}, "slow");
});
```

When I change .animate with .effect , next div is not showing.

JSFIDDLE with the change: http://jsfiddle.net/tHZLY/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using 2 different methods to show/hide divs.

You should use either `slide` or `width`.

*Width* of not `.active` divs is initially set to `0px` in CSS, so that they can be animated later on, using `.animate({"width": 200})` . But it does not work with `.effect('slide', ...)` as it deos not actually affect the *width* property.

`.animate({"width": 0})` does not make the element invisible, while you're applying `.hide()` on:

```
.effect('slide',{direction:'right',mode:'hide'});
```

Check this [**experiment**](http://jsfiddle.net/fzh31uq3/) .

---

To get this to work with `.effect('slide', ...)`, you should remove `width: 0px;` from CSS of the divs, place all `.page` divs at one position (for demo purposes used simple `position: absolute;`) and do not mix 2 different *show/hide* methods on *prev/next*:

```
// hide not active divs:
$('.page:not(.active)').hide();
$('#nxt').click(function(){
    var $cur = $('.page.active');
    var $next = $cur.next('.page');

    if ($next.length == 0) return;

    $cur.removeClass('active').effect('slide',{direction:'left',mode:'hide'});
    $next.addClass('active').effect('slide',{direction:'right',mode:'show'});
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    var $cur = $('.page.active');
    var $prev = $cur.prev('.page');

    if ($prev.length == 0) return;

    // do not mix up .aniamte(width) with .effect(slide)!
    $cur.removeClass('active').effect('slide',{direction:'right',mode:'hide'});
    $prev.addClass('active').effect('slide',{direction:'left',mode:'show'});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2x2w7t9/)

Comment: Very useful.Especially the experiment.But I think your last jsfiddle is not working.Can you fix it?

Comment: Strange. There is an error on IE showing that: `"$" is undefined` (while using jQuery 2.0.2 and jQuery.UI). Updated link with latest jQuery. Should work on IE now.